# What underlying network is typically meant with ResNET?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, recurrent-neural-networks, residual-networks

When people talk about a ResNet architecture, they are talking about a neural network architecture with skip connections. But what basis network are they typically referring to? Feedforward-networks or CNNs? Are there applications of ResNets to RNNs or is that pointless because they are conceptually similar (https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03640v1)?

Comment: I think the original implementation was with Deep CNN's, but I think the idea also makes sense for MLPs -- possibly other architectures, but I would need to think more about this.

Comment: @DavidIreland
I looked it up and it has indeed been applied for MLPs as well (see e.g. here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.03404). Then probably CNNs and MLPs are the most reasonable application areas. Have you had the chance to think about it more or do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the [official paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf) that introduced residual connections named their network(s) `ResNet`, so when somebody says `ResNet` I would assume that they mean an architecture following the original, i.e. convolutional layers with residual connections in between (see [here](https://pi-tau.github.io/posts/res-nets/#the-residual-block-empowering-deeper-networks) if you want more details about the architecture).

If I want to describe a network architecture with fully-connected layers that uses residual connections I would say exactly this.. fcnn with residual connections.

Regarding RNNs, I think that the design of the LSTM cell greatly resembles the [highway networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.00387.pdf). In fact I think that the highway networks were inspired by the LSTM (also both are authored by the same guy Jürgen Schmidhuber). For sequential tasks I would say that using gated summation makes more sense than the simple summation that residual connections use. However, I think that there are some ideas to apply residual connections between the layers of a multi-layer rnn.

[image: multi-layer rnn with residuals]